# how to loop throw all rows in data grid view in vb.net windows application

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

i have a data grid view..in update button i wrote the code like this

```
Dim cid As Integer
        Dim dtid As Integer
        Dim cmpname As String
        Dim dtname As String
        Dim dtPhone As String
        Dim dtEmail As String
Dim rv = DirectCast(bSource.Current, DataRowView)
        cid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("Cid")
        dtid = rv.Row.Field(Of Integer)("dtId")
        cmpname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("CompanyName")
        dtname = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtName")
        dtPhone = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtPhone")
        dtEmail = rv.Row.Field(Of String)("dtEmail")
 adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE CompanyMaster_tbl SET CompanyName = @CompanyName", con)
        adapter.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand("update DepartmentMaster_tbl set dtName = @dtName,dtPhone = @dtPhone,dtEmail = @dtEmail  where dtId=@dtid", con)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", cid)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpname)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtId", dtid)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtName", dtname)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtPhone", dtPhone)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtEmail", dtEmail)
        adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

i am new in datagridview.same time if i update multiple row,it s affecting last updated rows,,so i need to loop throw all rows in datagridview..how i can achieve that..

so i given the entire code inside the loop like this

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In gv.Rows
    'my code here
Next
```

but then also updating last updated row?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In gv.Rows
Cmd = new Sqlcommand("insert into tblemp (empid,empval) values("& rw.cells(0).value &",'"& rw.cells(1).value&"')",con)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'row' and not Current:

```
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In gv.Rows
        ...
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cid", Row.Cells("cid").Value)
        ...
        adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()  
    Next
```

Comment: sir,,while giving this getting error:system.data.sqlclient.row' is not accessible in this context because it is 'friend'

Comment: I assume this is VB (row vs Row) are different in C#. Not sure what else it could be. Did you remove the DirectCast logic? Note we are trying to access the 'row' in the For Each row... not rv.Row